# PowerBI Report Server (on prem) - securing the CacheRefreshPlan API

Tags: api, rest, permissions, powerbi

I am looking for information on how the API for the CacheRefreshPlan is secured for an on-prem PowerBI Report Server? It seems like I am able to call the API using the identity of any authenticated user on my Windows domain. I have tried with several different user accounts, the refresh is allowed for every account, all domain users, as long as they authenticated correctly.  Wrong password, no access. Correct password, the API refresh works.

I am testing using the Postman tool. On a successful POST action to the API, Postman shows "HTTP status 204 No Content. The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content". The RSPortal log and the report shows the refresh is successful.

I just want to understand how it all works before moving from Test to Production